# Fatal error display when run php code to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I got this problem when I run php code to connect with database in mysql.. Can anybody help me? I'm stuck.

Error:

> fatal error call to undefined function mysql_connect() in php

Php code:

```
?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("dadadsdb") or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Don't use `mysql*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead of mysql.

```
$con = mysqli_query("host","username","password","database");
```

Mysql has been deprecated in **PHP 5.5** for various reason and it can be replaced with MySQLi OOP(Object Oriented Programming) or the normal procedural style.
You can also use PDO that is more secure than MySQL.

Comment: I already change mysql_* to mysqli_* just like what you have write. But still not working. It turns out to be

error : mysqli_select_db() expects parameter exactly 2 parameters

Comment: @aniys Do not use the mysqli_select_db function if you have already put the database name in mysqli_connect.

Comment: okay as you said. but still got error. Is it because i'm using php version 7?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* functions are deprecated in newer PHP versions and in PHP 7 they are just gone. If you are using PHP 5.x you could install these modules by `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` (sometimes it is `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`  but I recommend you to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).